# В AJAX-запросе на контроллер приходит пустая модель

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здравствуйте!
Имеется контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model, string captcha)
{
    User result;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(captcha) || GoogleCaptcha.Validate(captcha) != "True")
    {
        result = new User
        {
            Error = "Проверка безопасности не была пройдена, повторите попытку",
            Status = 1
        };

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.OldPassword == null || model.Password == null || model.ConfirmPassword == null)
        {
            result = new User
            {
                Error = "Все поля являются обязательными",
                Status = 1
            };

            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        }

        result = new User
        {
            Error = "При смене пароля произошла непредвиденная ошибка",
            Status = 1
        };

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
    }
    ...
    // тут уже остальная логика
}
```

скрипт, который получает данные с формы:

```
function ChangePassword() {
    $('.messageBox').empty();
    var formData = $('#ChangePasswordForm').serialize();
    var captchaCode = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();

    if ($('#ChangePasswordForm').valid() == true) {
        $('#change-password-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ChangePassword',
            data: { formData: formData, captcha: captchaCode },
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (jsonResult.Status == 0) {
                    $('#ChangePasswordForm').css('display', 'none');
                    $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.messageBox').append('<div class="success"><p>Ваш пароль был успешно изменен на новый!</p></div>');
                }
                else {
                    $('#change-password-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.messageBox').append('<div class="errors">' + jsonResult.Error + '</div>');
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#change-password-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
                $('.messageBox').append('<div class="errors">' + jsonResult.Error + '</div>');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

и сама View с формой:

```
<form id="ChangePasswordForm" onsubmit="return false;" novalidate="novalidate">
        <table class="tableform" id="change-password-form">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @type = "password", @id = "OldPassword", @placeholder = "Введите старый пароль", @maxlength = "30", @size = "25" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @type = "password", @id = "Password", @placeholder = "Введите новый пароль", @maxlength = "30", @size = "25" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @type = "password", @id = "ConfirmPassword", @placeholder = "Повторите ввод нового пароля", @maxlength = "25", @size = "25" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Html.Label("Проверочный код")</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="123"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button id="change-password-button" onclick="ChangePassword();" class="add-button">Изменить пароль</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Нормально перестало работать после добавления google recaptcha, а именно этих строк в js:

```
var captchaCode = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
...
data: { formData: formData, captcha: captchaCode },
```

и этой во View:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="123"></div>
```

До этого вторая строка имела следующий вид и контроллер успешно отрабатывал:

```
data: formData,
```

Сейчас же на контроллере все валится на этой строке, т.к модель приходит пустая (определил, добавив логирование):

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

Собственно вопрос как сделать, чтобы корректно работало и модель и капча приходили на контроллер.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Укажите в функций **.ajax** дополнительное свойство **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"**, это связано с тем что подхватывается не правильный **ModelBinding**

Comment: @ivan_1988 не помогло...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ChangePassword',
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ formData: formData, captcha: captchaCode }),
    success: function (data) {
        var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (jsonResult.Status == 0) {
            $('#ChangePasswordForm').css('display', 'none');
            $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
            $('.messageBox').append('<div class="success"><p>Ваш пароль был успешно изменен на новый!</p></div>');
        }
        else {
            $('#change-password-button').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
            $('.messageBox').append('<div class="errors">' + jsonResult.Error + '</div>');
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#change-password-button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.messageBox').css('display', 'block');
        $('.messageBox').append('<div class="errors">' + jsonResult.Error + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: На контроллер приходит нужная модель, но пустая... Не могу понять почему в ней все свойства null

Comment: Нужно сериализовать форму в объект. Например, как [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: вообще-то у меня в скрипте есть строка var formData = $('#ChangePasswordForm').serialize();

Comment: .serialize() сериализует в строку, а не в объект